# Installing the latest AUCTeX from within Emacs

Tags: emacs, auctex, mac

Emacs 24+ comes with a package manager (`M-x list-packages`). This allows the user to install (and upgrade packages) by simply pressing `I` on the selected packages, with Emacs pulling from the right repositories (`mermelade`, `melpa`, `gnu`, etc.).

I am able to find one entry for AUCTeX (see snapshot below), but it looks old (and it seems to be the one I have installed already):

[image]

Can I install the latest version of AUCTeX in my system (OS X) using the package manager? If so how? and if not, would be a good way of doing it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just as with other `dired`-like modes, you have simply marked the package for install.  To actually do the installation, press `x` within the package manager after you mark it.

You can also delete old packages with `d`, but the install should just replace any existing copies automatically.

---

To do the installation from Lisp, you can simply run

```lisp
(package-install 'auctex)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried doing so on the entry shown in the snapshot, but nothing occurs. This could be because I have it installed already (I'm not sure what `unsigned` means). Do you know if the latest version is `11.87.4`?

Comment: @user815423426 That sounds right.  As for the `unsigned` bit, it looks like a problem with package list integrity: http://superuser.com/q/665724/#comment841043_665724.